# After using pdftotext: find page of string from txt

Tags: python-3.x, pdftotext

I am currently coding in python and managed to use pdftotext in order to extract the text from a pdf.

That particular text file is split up in a list of strings. By using regular expression I am able to find specific words I am interested in. The reason why I divide the text into a list is that I want to measure the distance between two specific words and by distance I mean the number of words in between the two words.

However after finding the position of the words I would like to be able to refer back to the initial pdf. In detail, I am interested in the page and maybe even line (if pdf supports this kind of structure) where these words are located.

One idea I have is to do this process for each page of the pdf, so when I find these words I know on what page this was. But this has the big disadvantage that sometimes page breaks are not necessarily natural. Meaning, I would lose the ability to find the words if they are unfortunately separated by a page break.

Do you have any idea how to do this in a more sophisticated manner?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a more sophisticated library than the one you're using. The [Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit](http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdfjavatoolkit/) has several classes that can extract text from a PDF file. The one you use depends on what you want to do with the text after extraction. The ReadingOrderTextExtractor will create a list of lists that will allow you to extract the text and examine the content of paragraphs, sentences within those paragraphs, and words within that sentence. You'll not only be able to tell the distance between the words but whether they are in the same sentence or paragraph. One you've found a Word object, you can then find both it's location on the page, allowing for highlighting, and the page number it's on.